# When I use my own function in a group_by() and summarize() chain, it incorrectly returns the same result for each group

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm sure I'm missing something about how grouping works. When I use my own function within a summarize statement (after grouping) I get the same result for each group, which is wrong. Also I don't get any errors or warnings, it's just silently giving me the wrong answer.

My goal is to get this custom function to play nice with group_by.

Here is the code:

```
library(dplyr)

#data
transect <- data.frame(acronym  = c("ABEESC", "ABIBAL", "AMMBRE", "ANTELE", "ABEESC", "ABIBAL", "AMMBRE"),
                       quad_id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2))
#scores
c_scores <- data.frame(acronym  = c("ABEESC", "ABIBAL", "AMMBRE", "ANTELE"),
                       c = c(5, 6, 6, 10))

#custom fun
my_fun <- function(data, scores){
  join <- left_join(data, scores, by = "acronym")
  mean <- mean(join$c)
  return(mean)
}

#this works
my_fun(transect, c_scores)

#this also works
transect %>% my_fun(., c_scores)

#this doesn't...
transect %>%
  group_by(quad_id) %>%
  summarise(mean_c = my_fun(., scores = c_scores))
```

this is my result:

| quad_id | mean_c |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 6.29 |
| 2 | 6.29 |

this is what I want:

| quad_id | mean_c |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 6.75 |
| 2 | 5.66 |

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We may use `cur_data()` as input to the function instead of `.` as `.` can take the full dataset instead of subset of data in the group

```
library(dplyr)
transect %>%
  group_by(quad_id) %>%
  summarise(mean_c = my_fun(cur_data(), scores = c_scores))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  quad_id mean_c
    <dbl>  <dbl>
1       1   6.75
2       2   5.67
```

---

If we want a `message` when it is grouped, then use `is_grouped_df`

```
my_fun2 <- function(data, scores)
 {
  
  if(dplyr::is_grouped_df(data))
  {
   message("data is grouped, so use cur_data() as data")
  }
  
 left_join(data, scores, by = "acronym") %>%
       pull(c) %>%
       mean
  
 
}
```

-testing

```
 > transect %>%
 +   group_by(quad_id) %>%
 +   summarise(mean_c = my_fun2(., scores = c_scores))
 data is grouped, so use cur_data() as data
 data is grouped, so use cur_data() as data
 # A tibble: 2 × 2
   quad_id mean_c
     <dbl>  <dbl>
 1       1   6.29
 2       2   6.29
 > transect %>%
 +   group_by(quad_id) %>%
 +   summarise(mean_c = my_fun2(cur_data(), scores = c_scores))
 # A tibble: 2 × 2
   quad_id mean_c
     <dbl>  <dbl>
 1       1   6.75
 2       2   5.67
```

Note that the messages are repeated as the function is applied multiple times (n number of groups) after the grouping when it is inside `summarise`.  If we do it outside, the message will be printed once

```
> transect %>% 
    group_by(quad_id) %>% 
    my_fun2(., c_scores)
data is grouped, so use cur_data() as data
[1] 6.285714
```

---

If we want a single function, we may also do

```
my_fun3 <- function(data, scores, grps = NULL)
{
data <- left_join(data, scores, by = "acronym")
if(!missing(grps)) 
{
 data <- data %>%
    group_by(across(all_of(grps)))

}
data %>%
    summarise(mean_c = mean(c, na.rm = TRUE))

}
```

-testing

```
>  my_fun3(transect, c_scores, "quad_id")
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  quad_id mean_c
    <dbl>  <dbl>
1       1   6.75
2       2   5.67
> 
> my_fun3(transect, c_scores)
    mean_c
1 6.285714
```

---

or simplify without any `if` condition using `missing` by making use of `any_of` in `group_by`

```
my_fun3 <- function(data, scores, grps = NULL)
{
left_join(data, scores, by = "acronym") %>%
    group_by(across(any_of(grps))) %>% 
    summarise(mean_c = mean(c, na.rm = TRUE))

}
```

-testing

```
> my_fun3(transect, c_scores, "quad_id")
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  quad_id mean_c
    <dbl>  <dbl>
1       1   6.75
2       2   5.67
> my_fun3(transect, c_scores)
# A tibble: 1 × 1
  mean_c
   <dbl>
1   6.29
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun! This is super helpful! I was wondering if there is anything I can change inside the function to make it 1. behave more like a typical group_by friendly function or 2. create a warning when it's used with group_by? My actual function is a lot more complicated and will be used by other people...it seems like mistakes could easily be made. Also, I'm new to stack, let me know if this should be a different question.

Comment: @ifoxfoot your conditions are not clear.  If you want to check for grouped, you can use `dplyr::is_grouped_df(data)` assuming the data is grouped

Comment: @ifoxfoot perhaps the update helps you

Comment: Okay, thanks, that helps with condition 2. To rephrase condition 1, what can I do to my function to make it work without `cur_data()`? Is it even possible? Like how `n()` and `mean()` work inside summarize without `cur_data()`. I don't understand the mechanism that makes them different from my function...I'm pretty sure I'm just missing something about how `group_by()` works. Or maybe how `.` works

Comment: @ifoxfoot  Why can't you use `cur_data()` in all cases i.e. if it is not grouped, it will be the full dataset or if it is grouped, then only the grouped data?

Comment: @ifoxfoot Also, assuming that you are creating a functional flow, then can't you make a wrapper function that groups or not and calls the my_fun2 in summarise?.  In that case you may just need `my_main_fun(transect, c_scores, grps = "quad_id")`

Comment: @ifoxfoot try the update in the post